# Calculating the amount of g's on a car tire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

I am trying to calculate how many g's are applied on a car tire during transit.
What I recall from my previous physics knowledge is that the formula to calculate the centripetal force is : $$F = \frac{m*v^2}{r}$$

I am assuming here that:

- the mass of the tire is 12kg
- the radius of the tire is 0.1909m
- the car is moving at a speed of 100km/h = 27.778 m/s

Am I wrong to assume that the amount of g's applied then is equal to: $$ F = \frac{12*(27.778^2)}{0.1909} = 4954.6g$$

the amount just seems strange to me, am I missing something? making wrong assumptions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) This is a minor nitpick, but it is "g's" not "G's". 2) Yes, that is a wrong assumption because it would only work like that if all the mass of the tire were on the outer edge. The mass is distributed throughout, so this isn't a sufficient equation. 3) your units are wrong. You can't use km/h with kg and m. Convert everything to kg, m, and s if you want to end up with Newtons (N)

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't copy my notes correctly, I should have fixed it now. In response to (2) how would I fix the equation then?

Comment: The question is a bit hard to approach. Where do you want to know the g's applied? This will be different at different parts of the tire. In general, however, the number of g's refers to an acceleration experienced, not a force. So what you can do is take the RPM of the tires, multiply that by $2\pi$, square it, multiply it by the radius of the point of interest on the tires, then divide that by $9.81\,m/s^2$ and that will give you the number of g's that part of the tire experiences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about g's, you are talking about acceleration, not force. So, we use the formula for centripetal acceleration of the outside rim of the tire:
$$a = \frac{v^2}{r}$$
where $a$ is the acceleration, $v$ is the velocity of the outside edge of the tire, and $r$ is the radius of the tire.
$$a = \frac{v^2}{r} = \frac{27.778^2}{0.1909} = 4,042~m/s^2$$
Since $$1~g = 9.8~m/s^2,$$ we can write $$4,042~m/s^2 = 412.4~g$$